# Adding script tags as a STRING to get JSON-P doesn't work

Tags: javascript, json, string, jsonp

Thats my code after a lot of tweaks:

```
var twitchApp = (function () {

 var streamers = ["ESL_SC2", "OgamingSC2", "cretetion", "freecodecamp", "storbeck", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas"];
 var url = 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/';
 var body = document.body;
 var container = document.getElementById('container');
 var cb = "?callback=twitchApp.handleJSON";

// function addScriptTags() {
//  streamers.forEach(function (streamer) {
//      var script = document.createElement("script");
//      body.appendChild(script);
//      script.src = url + streamer + cb;
//      body.removeChild(script);
//  });
//
// }


function addScriptTags() {

    var scriptTags = streamers.map(createScriptTag).join("\n");

    body.innerHTML += scriptTags;

}

function createScriptTag(streamer) {
    var src = "src=\"" + url + streamer + cb + "\"";
    var script = "<script " + src + "></script>";

    return script;
}

var handleJSON = function (data) {
    var prepareData = data;
    console.log(data);
};
    function addStreamers(streamerName) {
    streamers.push(streamerName);
}

function removeStreamer(streamerName) {
    streamers = streamers.map(function (streamer) {
        return streamer !== streamerName;
    });
}

return {
    handleJSON: handleJSON,
    addScriptTags: addScriptTags,
    addStreamers: addStreamers,
    removeStreamer: removeStreamer
};

 })();

 twitchApp.addScriptTags();
```

Im using this code to get from Twitch's Api informations about current streamers. Im supposed to get informations about all streamers in streamers array.
For sake of " performance " (never mind) I wanted to concat all script tags to single string instead of touching DOM 8 times. But its impossible to gather JSON this way. When I inspect it on developers tools script tags are added properly but they dont send me any JSON.

Commented out code is the only way it works. I tried before creating one script tag and replacing its .src property for different streamers but It worked only for first streamer in an array.
So tell me why its impossible to do it that way ?

Comment: You can not add script tags with innerHTML

Comment: The question is why if every different tag like a, li , div is possible.

Comment: Plenty of dupes, script is not evaluated.